# how to find the path of an image I want to upload?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-s3, ejs

I'm trying to learn AWS S3 and so I'm building a form for uploading and later for downloading images I upload.

Currently everything works if I upload an image that is in the same directory of the app. It will appear in my S3 bucket. But if I try to upload an image from another directory, I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'myphoto.jpg'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
at uploadFile (/home/morbi/bucketTest/upload.js:14:26)
at /home/morbi/bucketTest/app.js:65:3
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/morbi/bucketTest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/morbi/bucketTest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/morbi/bucketTest/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/morbi/bucketTest/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/morbi/bucketTest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/morbi/bucketTest/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Here is my form, it's a very simple form for testing purposes, index.ejs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bucket Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/bucket">Create Bucket</a>

    <form action="/" method="POST">
      <label for="img">Select image:</label>
      <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
// load .env data into process.env
require('dotenv').config();

// Web server config
const PORT       = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const ENV        = process.env.ENV || "development";
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const uploadFile = require("./upload.js");


// Enter copied or downloaded acess ID and secret key here
const ID = process.env.BUCKET_ID;
const SECRET = process.env.BUCKET_SECRET;

// The name of the bucket that you have created
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const BUCKET_AREA = process.env.BUCKET_AREA;

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET
});

const params = {
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/bucket", function(req,res){

  let string;

  s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
      string = data.location;
      console.log('Bucket Created Successfully', data.location);
    }
  });

  res.render("bucket", {string: string});
});

app.get("/upload", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  // let img = req.body;
  res.render("download");
});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
  let item = req.body.img;
  console.log(item);
  uploadFile(item);
  res.redirect("upload", /* {item: item} */);
});

app.listen(PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And here is my upload.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const ID = process.env.BUCKET_ID;
const SECRET = process.env.BUCKET_SECRET;

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET
});

const uploadFile = (fileName) => {
  // Read content from the file
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileName);

  // Setting up S3 upload parameters
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName, // File name you want to save as in S3
    Body: fileContent
  };

  // Uploading files to the bucket
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.location}`);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = uploadFile;
```

I am making the assumption that the reason it's not working is because when I select the file/image, it only passes the file's name and not it's path. So how do I attach the path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, came across a few videos on youtube where they used Multer and Multer-s3 but I didn't want to change my upload.js file to much so I came across express-upload package, created a folder inside my app directory to transfer the images before sending them up to my bucket and everything is ok.

Here are my updated files:

app.js:

```
// load .env data into process.env
require('dotenv').config();

// Web server config
const PORT       = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const ENV        = process.env.ENV || "development";
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const uploadFile = require("./upload.js");

const fileUps = require('express-fileupload');


// Enter copied or downloaded acess ID and secret key here
const ID = process.env.BUCKET_ID;
const SECRET = process.env.BUCKET_SECRET;

// The name of the bucket that you have created
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const BUCKET_AREA = process.env.BUCKET_AREA;

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET
});

const params = {
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(fileUps());

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/bucket", function(req,res){

  let string;

  s3.createBucket(params, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
      string = data.location;
      console.log('Bucket Created Successfully', data.location);
    }
  });

  res.render("bucket", {string: string});
});

app.get("/upload", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  // let img = req.body;
  res.render("download");
});

app.post("/", function(req,res){
  if(req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
  }
  const file = req.files.img;

  file.mv(`${__dirname}/uploads/${file.name}`, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }


  });

  console.log(file);

  uploadFile(file.data ,file.name);
  res.redirect("upload", {item: file.name});
});

app.listen(PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

and the upload.js:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const ID = process.env.BUCKET_ID;
const SECRET = process.env.BUCKET_SECRET;

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET
});

const uploadFile = (fileData, fileName) => {
  // Read content from the file
  const fileContent = fileData;

  // Setting up S3 upload parameters
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName, // File name you want to save as in S3
    Body: fileContent
  };

  // Uploading files to the bucket
  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.location}`);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = uploadFile;
```

now all i need to do is to delete the files inside the uploads folder after it's been sent up to s3 bucket so the server won't run out of space.

Hope this helps other people.